Private tutor job for UK skilled worker visa
Can private tutors working in tuition centres (a licenced sponsor) apply for the UK skilled worker visa?

From the list of eligible occupations in the education category, private tutor appears under job code 2319 -    Teaching professionals not elsewhere classified.
Eligibility may depend on the type of tutoring. A licensed sponsor should be able to advise you on that.
